# SOLR: Field with alphabetic ranges

Tags: solr

I am trying to get a field to be searched in as kind of a range. 
To be exactly I have elements in the field which look like this:

```
A-C
Sch-So
```

A search for `Banana` (B is in Range A-C) schould return the first document
and a search for `School` (*Sch* is matched in Sch-So) should deliver the second document. While `Salat` should return none of the above.

To make it more complex there can be multiple Values and Ranges in one document, so the following is also possible.

```
A, E-G
C, F, U
Sch-So, Pi-Re
```

So this means, that the first term should be found when anything beginning with A, or anything starting with an E, F or G is searched for.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to preprocess the documents before you index them, since there is no way in Solr to match 'banana' to 'a-c'. You should start with a custom [tokenizer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Tokenizers) that injects tokens into the token stream at index time. According to your example, this tokenizer would inject 'a', 'b' and 'c' into the token stream for the term 'a-c'.

Then you configure the field with the [`solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) analyzer for the query terms. You can control which n-grams the filter will create (e.g. start from the `side="front"`, `minGramSize="1"` and `maxGramSize="3"`). This will basically turn the search term 'banana' into the multiple terms 'b', 'ba', and 'ban'.

The query term 'school' will result in the n-grams 's', 'sc', 'sch' and therefore 'school' matches 'sch' in the index.

The query term 'salat' will result in the n-grams 's', 'sa', 'sal' etc. and therefore 'salat' **does not** match 'sch' in the index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this sounds like it will work. I can test this next week, as I'm on the road now, but I will provide feedback then.

Comment: I now had time to test it and it almost worked as I wanted it to. I had to make a little adjustment as you also need to split the index "Sch-So" into "Sch, Sci, Scj...Shz, Sd, Se,...So" in order for this to work. Thanks for the help again!